# Computing the matrix $ \begin{bmatrix} -5 & -3 \\ 7 & 4 \\ \end{bmatrix}^{98} $

Tags: matrices

**Hi! I have a problem with that matrix.**

I don't know how to (multiplying?) this matrix and show it in normal form (without any imaginary numbers). I guess I should try to get this in Jordan form?
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
-5 & -3 \\
7 & 4 \\
\end{bmatrix}^{98}
$$

Comment: What is your question? Would you like to calculate $A^{98}$, where $A$ is your given matrix?

Comment: [Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391/quick-beginner-guide-for-asking-a-well-received-question) + please [avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933).
 You don't seem to have tried to calculate at least $A^2$ and $A^3$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Characteristic equation of $A$(The given Matrix) is $x^{2}+x+1$ so $A$ satisfies this equation that is $A^{2}+A+I = 0 \implies (A - I)(A^{2}+A+I) = 0 \implies A^{3} = I$

Which implies that $A^{3} = I$ So $A^{98} = A^{96}\times A^{2} = (A^{3})^{32}\times A^{2} = A^{2}$, which is easy to calculate.